# How Do You Change AFNetworking Request's Temporary FilePath

Tags: ios, objective-c, download, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to migrate our ASIHTTPRequest code to AFNetworking. I'm okay with POST requests but I'm having issues with download requests. I can't seem to set the temporary file path of the content to be downloaded. In ASIHTTPRequest I can have a code like this:

```
    // Create file path
    NSString *filePath = [cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:package.fileName];
    NSString *tempFile = [tempPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:package.fileName];

    [downloadRequest setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:tempFile];
    [downloadRequest setDownloadDestinationPath:filePath];
```

How can I do this using AFNetworking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AFURLSessionManager* urlSessionManager = [AFURLSessionManager.alloc initWithSessionConfiguration:NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSProgress* progress = nil;
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://your.remote.file"]];
NSURLSessionDownloadTask* downloadTask = [urlSessionManager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:&progress destination:^NSURL* (NSURL* targetPath, NSURLResponse* response) {
    NSURL* targetFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/your/local/path" isDirectory:NO];
    return targetFileUrl;
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse* response, NSURL* filePath, NSError* error) {
    if (error)
    {
        // Some error occurred or download programmatically cancelled
    }
    else
    {
        // Download completed
    }
}];
[downloadTask resume];
```

The temporary files are managed by AFNetworking, usually they're hidden raw files inside your document dir.

Comment: One question, how is this different from using this function: (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)GET:(NSString *)URLString
                     parameters:(id)parameters
                        success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                        failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure

Comment: `downloadTaskWithRequest:` is designed to download a potentially big content to local storage using a temporary file, you can also use the returned downloadTask object to control the download process, pause or resume it. 
With `GET:` you don't have the same flexibility, indeed the method is used to do simple GET calls.

Comment: i'm not really familiar with GET. Anyway, does this mean that GET does not use temporary storage? Moreover, I need the AFHTTPRequestOpration's userInfo property to add an additional data. If i use NSURLSessionDownloadTask, i won't be able to set a userInfo.

Comment: No, GET does not use temporary storage.
What do you mean with _an additional data_?

Comment: any additional info like date the request was sent, or the filename... basically any object i want to be included. kinda like ASIHTTPRequest's or AFHTTPOperation's userInfo property. It can hold any object you want.

Comment: maybe i can use AFHTTPDownloadRequestOperation for that?